# Integration: A question

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> How is  $$\int ^2 _1 \frac{1}{(x+2)^2-1^2}dx=\frac{1}{2(1)} \log |\frac{x+2-1}{x+2+1}| ?$$

This is an extract of a solution and i didnt understand this part.

Please offer your assistance

Thank you :)

Comment: Please edit your question : LHS does not depend on $x$ and the RHS does...

Comment: sorry i skipped it. edit made

Comment: Still not good...

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Use $$\frac1{(x+2)^2-1^2}=\frac1{(x+3)(x+1)}=\frac12\frac{(x+3)-(x+1)}{(x+3)(x+1)}=\frac12\left(\frac1{x+1}-\frac1{x+3}\right)$$

and $\displaystyle \int\frac{dx}{x+m}=\ln|x+m|+C$

In general, we can use  [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Procedure) as follows $$\frac1{(x+3)(x+1)}=\frac A{x+1}+\frac B{x+3}$$

and find $A,B$ by comparing the coefficients of $x,x^0$

Answer (score 2):

Notice by using the substitution $t = x + 2$ and using the partial fractions trick, you obtain:

$$\int  \frac{dx}{(x+2)^2-1^2} = \int  \frac{dt}{t^2-1^2} = \frac{1}{2} [ \int \frac{dt}{t-1} - \int \frac{dt}{t +1} ] = \frac{1}{2} [ \ln (t-1) - \ln (t +1) = \frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{t-1}{t+1}$$

Now substitute back and you get desired result.

Comment: +1. .. is there any other quicker way like using inverse tigonometric ratios or something?

Comment: this is the quickest way! :D